# Riddle Me This. What Object am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am an object.

Hard at heart, I can be shaped the same,
Thickened, I added to Nostradamus's fame,
My two faces are sharp or sweet
While the air grows warm, I am a delightful treat
Often in pairs, but enjoyed alone. 
Pop me in your mouth and try not to moan.

HINT:

> I have a bag of these on the desk in front of me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> A Cherry

Hard at heart, I can be shaped the same

> Cherries have pits and can be shaped like hearts

Thickened, I added to Nostradamus's fame

> Only one I looked up (others make the answer obvious), he published cherry jelly recipes

My two faces are sharp or sweet

> Cherries can taste sharp or sweet

While the air grows warm, I am a delightful treat

> Good to eat while warm (pies)

Often in pairs, but enjoyed alone

> Cherries often come in twos (slot machine symbols)

Pop me in your mouth and try not to moan

> Not sure

Comment: How the hell are my riddles this obvious? And as to the last line, I bloody love cherries. But the air warm is a reference because cherries ripen in summer

Comment: You do realise that that comment gives the answer away?

Comment: Yeah, what is the point of hiding spoilers when the non-hidden comments tell you the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Coin

?

> Hard at heart, I can be shaped the same,

A coin heart is hard, but texture is same, size is same from the heart to the end.

> Thickened, I added to Nostradamus's fame, My two faces are sharp or
>   sweet

A coin has two face, a face of hard/sharp icon and a face of flower [sweet]

> While the air grows warm, I am a delightful treat

We roll a coin by the air supported beside, a coin is delightfully rolling.

> Often in pairs, but enjoyed alone.
>   Pop me in your mouth and try not to moan.

A coin is often seems pairs because of its two face. but we can always see one face when we put it on a surface.
You can't moan coin in your mouth.

HINT:

```
I have a bag of these on the desk in front of me.
```

We usually put coins in bag and you put it on your desk, isn't it? ^_^